# how to return a specific element from array of strings and json using php

Tags: php, json

```
Array ( [0] => [[["15:30"," ","Alemania","Germany"," Bundesliga: ","Bayer Leverkusen - SC Freiburg"]]] [1] => [[["15:30"," ","Polonia","Poland"," Ekstraklasa: ","MKS Sandecja Nowy Sacz - Termalica Bruk-Bet Nieciecza"]]] [2] => [[["15:30"," ","Rusia","Russia"," Premier League: ","FC Rubin Kazan - FC Ural Yekaterinburg"]]] [3] => [[["16:00"," ","Albania","Albania"," Kategoria Superiore: ","KF Laci - Luftetari Gjirokaster"]]] [4] => [[["16:00"," ","Brasil","Brazil"," Brasileir\u00e3o Serie A: ","Avai SC - Atletico Mineiro MG"]]]
```

How can I get the data from this object using php , for example i need to get the time and save it in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need  the time

assuming you have $myArray

```
    $myArray =  Array ( [0] => [[["15:30"," ","Alemania","Germany"," Bundesliga: ","Bayer Leverkusen - SC Freiburg"]]] 
          [1] => [[["15:30"," ","Polonia","Poland"," Ekstraklasa: ","MKS Sandecja Nowy Sacz - Termalica Bruk-Bet Nieciecza"]]] 
          [2] => [[["15:30"," ","Rusia","Russia"," Premier League: ","FC Rubin Kazan - FC Ural Yekaterinburg"]]] 
          [3] => [[["16:00"," ","Albania","Albania"," Kategoria Superiore: ","KF Laci - Luftetari Gjirokaster"]]] 
          [4] => [[["16:00"," ","Brasil","Brazil"," Brasileir\u00e3o Serie A: ","Avai SC - Atletico Mineiro MG"]]] );
```

you could use

```
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
      $myTime[$key]=  $value[0][0][0] ;
    }
```

in $myTime = have an array with only the time

Comment: Hi Bro , Thanks for your solution , I  found that I make the array in not correct way , BTW your code is working and thanks